# Can't get array_push working

Tags: php, arrays, soap, case

I want to add values to an array so the output will be like this (1,2,3,4,5).
To accomplish this i tried to use array_push. I've tried a lot to get this working but it just outputs the last number which in this case is '5'. Do you guys see what is wrong with my code? Thanks in advance!

```
$websites = array();

                    case 'Hengelsport':
                        if ($waarde == 'true') {
                            array_push($websites,1);}
                        break;

                    case 'Diervoeders':
                        if ($waarde == 'true') {
                            array_push($websites,2);}
                        break;

                    case 'Vijverconcurrent':
                        if ($waarde == 'true') {
                            array_push($websites,3);}
                        break;

                    case 'Broqx':
                        if ($waarde == 'true') {
                            array_push($websites,4);}
                        break;

                    case 'Dekrabpaal':
                        if ($waarde == 'true') {
                            array_push($websites,5);}
                        break;


                $this->articleData['website_ids'] = $websites;
```

Comment: Did you forget to add switch word?

Comment: @Oyeme +1. And, why don't you wrap your `switch` around `if ($waarde == 'true')` since you are always doing this test. Also you should consider using a `boolean` instead of `'true'`.

Comment: You should have put up the question like my `switch` case didn't work :)

Comment: you have done wrong switch-case statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can't to have other value that last number, if you juste set `$websites` variable, like this : `$websites = array();`

And don't forget switch operator.

```
switch ($i) {
    case "Hengelsport":
        echo "i égal 0";
        if ($waarde == 'true') {
            array_push($websites,1);
        }
        break;
    //...
}
```

Is it full code that you show us ?

Answer (score 0):

Or for an easy way :

```
$website_ids = array(
    'Hengelsport' => 1,
    'Diervoeders' => 2,
    'Vijverconcurrent' => 3,
    'Broqx' => 4,
    'Dekrabpaal' => 5
);

if ($waarde == 'true') 
{
    array_push($websites, $website_ids[$your_var_containing_name]);
}
```